# Why was the ISO module standard for prolog a failure?

Tags: module, prolog, standards, iso, iso-prolog

In the introduction [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modules), it states that the ISO module standard for Prolog was a failure. Can anyone elaborate on this?

Comment: This question and the accepted answer are based on a misunderstanding. The linked section says "Prolog modules are defined by an ISO standard. Unfortunately, the standard is considered a failure and, as far as we are aware, not implemented by any concrete Prolog implementation." The standard being referred to here is clearly _ISO/IEC 13211-2_, i.e. _ISO Prolog - Part 2: Modules_ and not the entire ISO Prolog standard.

Comment: @MichaelBenYosef: You can certainly read the text as you did ; however better look at the concrete system and what it does. See my answer for this.

Comment: @false: I followed closely the announcement of SWI7 and the ensuing arguments over non-conformance, so I'm well aware of the situation. Personally, I try to write conforming code while using SWI. But I think there is an interesting question lurking here, albeit one that is also inappropriate for SO: Why do systems like the two you cited embrace _ISO/IEC 13211-1_ while _ISO/IEC 13211-2_ is almost universally ignored.

Comment: @MichaelBenYosef: " I try to write conforming code " how do you do this in SWI?

Comment: By avoiding everything listed [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=extensions): dicts, strings, `'.'` as a function symbol, and the non-conforming `[a|b] \== .(a,b)` and `[] \== '[]'`.

Comment: SWI-documentation is not suited for conformity considerations.

Comment: @MichaelBenYosef: In any case, please take the last par in my answer seriously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system you cite, SWI-Prolog, is a system whose core is developed by a single developer. Such bold statements as those you quote are his very personal opinions. In the past, SWI did follow ISO standards for a certain period.  Then, recently changed. If you want to read more about this, please refer to [this answer](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/SWI7_and_ISO).

There are systems that are conforming - in particular: SICStus Prolog [sicstus-prolog](/questions/tagged/sicstus-prolog) and GNU Prolog [gnu-prolog](/questions/tagged/gnu-prolog).

In case you want to know more about the purpose of standards, in particular ISO standards, refer to your national standardization body. They certainly offer 1- or 2-day introductory courses. SO is not a place to discuss this.

Comment: Please see my comment under the question.

Comment: I edited the question, from ISO standard to ISO module standard. The link in the question points to ISO module standard, and not ISO (core) standard.